# maven cargo: not deploying with running test

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey, maven-cargo

My integration `pom.xml` looks like

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.org.me_services.inventory</groupId>
        <artifactId>services</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                    <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.16/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.16.zip</url>
                        <downloadDir>${project.build.directory}/downloads</downloadDir>
                        <extractDir>${project.build.directory}/extracts</extractDir>
                    </zipUrlInstaller>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <!--<cargo.rmi.port>1099</cargo.rmi.port>-->
                        <cargo.servlet.port>9090</cargo.servlet.port>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>com.org.me_services.inventory</groupId>
                        <artifactId>services</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-tomcat</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-tomcat</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and my Integration Test looks like

```java
public class TestHello {
    @Test
    public void testHello() {
        final String url = "http://localhost:8080/hello";
        final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        final WebTarget target = client.target(url).path("hello");
        final Invocation.Builder builder = target.request();
        final Response response = builder.get();

        assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

When I run `mvn clean install` on module, i get the following error

```java
testHello(com.org.me_services.inventory.integration.TestHello)  Time elapsed: 0.435 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:655)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:291)
    at com.yahoo.pryme_services.inventory.integration.TestHello.testHello(TestHello.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:321)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:227)
    ... 40 more
```

seems like cargo **does not** deploys the war file. What am I missing here?

Also when run `mvn cargo:run`, it seems to deploy the war file correctly on Tomcat

**update**
I renamed my test to `HelloResourceIT` and pointed test to port `9090`, but the error is still the same

Comment: You have defined the port in your cargo configuration 9090 but your test tries to connect to port 8080? Furthermore you didn't name you test based on the maven-failsafe-plugin naming conventions like `FirstIT.java` etc. So what you've posted couldn't be the real configuration your are using.

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you said, but error is still the same. Problem is I do not see tomcat and war being deployed, something basic is missing

Comment: @user3600328 Facing similar issue. How was this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```xml
<execution>
    <id>start-tomcat</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

To

```xml
<execution>
    <id>start-tomcat</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>start</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```